# how to set an apple watch app's display name

Tags: apple-watch

I can't seem to find where to set the product name of my apple watch app. I do see the option Product Name, but updating it doesn't do anything. Also do not see anything in the documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all App's display name is different than Product Name.

How to change App's display name:
Find the Info.plist file that is located in your WatchKit App folder and change the key "Bundle display name" (CFBundleDisplayName).

How to change Product Name:
I am not sure why xCode does't allow to set the Product Name when creating a new WatchKit app.
If you search for "PRODUCT_NAME", you will find that the WatchKit app is using the TARGET_NAME as product name "PRODUCT_NAME = $(TARGET_NAME)" for the WatchKit app. 
So you can just rename the target name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not address the question. The correct answer is given by Scenario.

Answer (score 7):

To get your app name to display properly in the Apple Watch app on iPhone, note that Apple screwed up and used the wrong key.

You must set CFBundleName to the same string as your CFBundleDisplayName in your *iPhone target's* Info.plist (not any other target).

That key can also be edited via the "Custom iOS Target Properties" editor. This is especially important if your app name has a space in it but your target name doesn't.

I wasted a whole Saturday tracking this bug down. So hopefully this will help someone!

Comment: I believe you are right. but if the CFBundleName is not English then it will be XXXX.app, XXXX.ipa and also the executive file is also XXXX ( XXXX is non-English), it's really unacceptable of an non-English executive file name